# Django model choice field naming convention

Tags: python, django, naming-conventions

What is the naming convention for the names of a choice field.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    ACTIVE= 'active'
    INACTIVE= 'inactive'
    NOT_AVAILABLE= 'not-available'
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (ACTIVE, 'Active'),
        (INACTIVE, 'Inactive'),
        (NOT_AVAILABLE, 'Not available'),
    )
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=15,
        choices=STATUS_CHOICES ,
        default=INACTIVE,
    )
```

What naming convention should I choose for the NOT_AVAILABLE field?

**not-available** or **not_available**

Comment: Well it is a string, so it does not matter...

Comment: But I would advice you to use `not_available`, since this is the lowercase equivalent of `NOT_AVAILABLE`, hence you can for example fetch the attribute of that model.

Comment: But there is no convention. The idea is that you will store the left tuple item in the database. So if you like to store `'not-available'` in the database, then the former should be used. If you think `not_available` is more readable, then you should go for the latter.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much. I was just unsure what to choose. I will take not_available. There are so many conventions in Python, so I thought there is one for this case too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing magical about these `choices`. The left tuple items (let us call these the *keys*) are stored *in* the database, and the right tuple items (let us call these the *values*) are the *display*s of these values (so a more human readable value).

The idea is that the *values* can be *culture-variant* (for example depending on the language get translated), whereas the *keys* are *invariant*: regardless of the settings, the keys are typically always the same. Since these are stored in the database, these do not have to be pretty, since the programmer should be able to understand what they mean. If one would however translate keys as well, then this could imply that after changing the language of a server, Django can no longer *interpret* the rows that contain items in the old translation. Since `'active'` is of course not equal to `'actief'` (Dutch translation).

My personal advice is to use the underscore here, since then it is a Python identifier as well, so you could then later use it for a `getattr(..)` operation. For example:

```
getattr(Student, some_student.status.upper())
```

could then be used to obtain `STUDENT.NOT_AVAILABLE` in case `some_student` has as `status` the `'not_available'` string, but as said before, there can be both reasons for the former, and the latter approach.